# The term 'get-splogevent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to Sharepoint... and I'm trying to deploy a simple web part.

When I do deploy it and place it on a page, I get an error with a correlation id.

Now, I'm trying to get details about the error, and using Powershell I type...

```
 get-splogevent | ?{$_Correlation -eq "bcce1b39-f277-4b2b-b8f8-4c113a30f193" }
```

But it's giving me an error....

```
The term 'get-splogevent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ get-splogevent <<<<  | ?{$_Correlation -eq "bcce1b39-f277-4b2b-b8f8-4c113a30f193" }
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-splogevent:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Had the PSSnapin for SharePoint been added into the Powershell session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was starting the solo powershell instead of the sharepoint one. In the task bat there is "Sharepoint 2010 Management Shell", using that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you are on an ordinary Powershell session. The Sharepoint management snap-in is not being loaded, so cmdlet is not found. Take a look at [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/11/14/add-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-snap-in-to-all-powershell-windows.aspx) that describes how to load the snap-in automatically to all Powershell sessions.

The snap-in is loaded manually like so,

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

Comment: I just tried it and I get the message:

Add-PSSnapin : Cannot add Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.SharePoint.Power
Shell because it is already added. Verify the name of the snap-in and try again